# Почему FF странно реагирует на position?

Tags: css

Здравствуйте!
У меня на сайте справка-азов.рф/test есть оранжевая кнопка "Бесплатная регистрация...", перед надписью стоит плюс, в Хроме он стоит нормально, а в ФФ этот плюс улетает в начало страницы, и позиционируется относительно нее, почему так? Я ставлю этот плюс через span, делаю ему position:absolute с соотв. координатами относительно родителя, которому задаю position:relative, что не так делаю?!

Comment: эту проблему можно решить, но лучше просто не использовать таблицы вместо div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте промежуточную обёртку с position: relative; между плюсом и ячейкой. Потому что ячейка в таблице не может являться родителем с position: relative.

Comment: Да, странно, вроде согласно справочнику position применяется ко всем элементам...

Answer (score -1):

ну пропишите для ФФ отдельно @-moz-document url-prefix